# MKLocalSearch not finding all nearby restaurants

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mklocalsearch, mklocalsearchrequest

I implemented an MKLocalSearch within a certain region on the mkmapview that returns an array of restaurants within the region. Through research, only 10 restaurants are being shown. Is there's a way so that the MKLocalSearch can return more than 10 restaurants within a region? Here is the code,

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc]init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurant";
request.region = midRegion;

MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];
    [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithPlacemark:item.placemark];
        annotation.title = item.name;
        annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
        annotation.phone = item.phoneNumber;

        [annotations addObject:annotation];
    }];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];

 }];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So although it's been a while since I've asked this question, I still want to address because I think I should. After stumbling across various links on stackoverflow and the apple developer forums, it seems that the built-in MKLocalSearch method is limited to returning up to 10 results. Whereas, the Google Maps API can return up to 60 results. Therefore, I'm afraid the answer to my question is

**No**, you can't get the MKLocalSearch method to return more than 10 locations within a region tied to a specific naturalLanguageQuery keyword.